# Authentication logic for sessions that last while tab is open

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, reactjs

Assume you are working on a front end application that performs authentication through 3rd party api. Successful authentication returns a json web token.

What would be best practices to store such token and create some sort of session for user while he is active on the website i.e. didn't close a tab or browser, however refreshing / reloading a page should not destroy such session.

Also, how can this session be used to protect routes? I am working with a stack consisting of react / redux / node / express and quiet a few other libraries. I believe I can perform certain checks within my react-router, however wouldn't it be better to do these on the express side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the token in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, and include it in every API request.

[Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) outlives the tab, it's stored there until you explicitly delete from it, so refreshing a page won't be a problem. Even closing a tab and then coming back won't be.

[Session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) allows you to store data. Page refreshes are fine, but tab closing isn't, which is closer to the behavior you want.

As for protecting routes, the server should obviously check the token on requests to all protected API routes.

On the browser side, you will probably want to show a login form if a user tries to visit a protected route but the token isn't there (or is invalid).

With react-router, you could do it like the official repo shows in the example, via `onEnter` hooks: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js

An alternative would be to create two top-level components, one for protected routes, one for public routes (like a landing page or the sign in/sign up forms). The protected handler will then in `componentWillMount` check if there's a token:

```
- PublicHandler 
  + SignIn
  + SignUp
  + Index

- ProtectedHandler
  + Dashboard
  + MoneyWithdrawal
```

Comment: I just had a thought that came to mind, say if someone sets a session with random string, they will gain access to `/dashboard` obviously they will not see any data there, as that random string is not a valid token, but still have access to restricted route

Comment: But without the backend, it won't be usable. What you could do is, call the server with the token initially to see if it's valid. If it is — everything's alright, if not, redirect to the login form.

Answer (score 1):

it may looks like that , with **sessionStorage** ([JWT](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/) token is accesseble, untill browser or tab closed)

```
///action creator redux
export const signupUser = creds => dispatch =>{
    dispatch(requestSignup());

    return API.auth.signup(creds)
    .then(res =>  {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', res.token);// <------------------
        dispatch(receiveSignup(res));
        return res;
    })
    .catch(err => {
            dispatch(SignupError(err));
         );
     });

};
```

**On client :** handling auth through HOC [redux-auth-wrapper](https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper)

**On server** on server you can use [passport-jwt](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt) strategy

```
passport.use('jwt',new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        User.findOne({where:{ id: jwt_payload.user.id }}).then(user=>{
            if (user) {
                done(null, jwt_payload.user);
            } else {
                done(null, false);
                // or you could create a new account
            }
        },err=>{
            console.log('Error ',err);
            return done(err,false);
        });

    }));
```

then just add route handler

```
var checkJWT = passport.authenticate('jwt')

router.get('/protected',checkJWT, (req, res) =>{
    res.json(req.user);
});
```

**You don't need sessions on server for that**